# Add striped background in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to change the background of a grid to stripes as shown in the image below.
[image]

How can I change solid color background to these kind of striped ones in xaml . ?

Comment: Dude, this background is awful. Please, do not use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I prefer not to add elements like images if I don't need to and leave these types of design additions more flexible in case I want to play off of them in the future with things like animations, or changing the pattern on the fly, or making them a resource, or having to worry about changing a file path or something, etc.

So for example instead of using an actual image let your xaml do that work for you by using stuff already available to you like a `LinearGradientBrush` as an alternative technique.

Something like;

```
<Grid Height="200" Width="200">
  <Grid.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" 
                         SpreadMethod="Repeat" 
                         StartPoint="0,0" 
                         EndPoint="3,3">
      <GradientStop Offset="0.125" Color="#77999999" />
      <GradientStop Offset="0.125" Color="#00000000" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Grid.Background>

  <TextBlock Text="Hey check it out,&#10;lines without an image!&#10;yay XAML! :)" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             FontWeight="Bold"/>

</Grid>
```

result;

[image: stripes with xaml]

For future reference though, generally you want to at least show some effort before asking help on a QA site like SO. Anyhow, hopes this helps, cheers.

Comment: Good point on the LinearGradientBrush. That works well for the specific case of stripes. Now fix your snippet so it doesn't break high contrast mode so I can vote it up :)

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT eh, no worries, I didn't even consider it from the question so +1 your way just for being so active and helping out guys like him on here. Also thanks for elaborating on top of it. There's always more than one way to skin a cat and it's nice helping people learn something new. ;)

Comment: It is however unnecessary to copy someones answer and append it to your own though, and sort of poor form. Know what I mean? Cheers Rob.

Comment: Just trying for completeness. I didn't want somebody to run into a cut & paste problem because we had two half-answers, and you hadn't updated before I was out the door.

Comment: Ya but it's an etiquette thing right? For instance if I copied your answer into my own in the same fashion, it would appear to a reader it's conveyed as an original thought. However it is the sincerest form of flattery ;)

Comment: I'd much rather you copied my answer into yours than leave it with a misleading (but all too common) accessibility bug :)

Comment: How's it a bug if there's always a default? ....but, whatever's clever amigo. Questions closed now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Grid.Background property to any brush type, including an ImageBrush (if you want an image) or a LinearGradiantBrush (which can be set to generate simple stripes). Naively:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/bgimage.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Or for stripes:

```
<Grid.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="3,3" StartPoint="0,0" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDFDFDD" Offset=".5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE8E8E6" Offset=".5"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Grid.Background>
```

In a real app you'll want to use the brush only in normal contrast modes and fall back to default backgrounds in high contrast modes. For this set the Background as a ThemeResource then provide the stripe brush in the Default ThemeDictionary and use the default brushes in the HighContrast ThemeDictionary.

In the page's Xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource PageBackground}">
</Grid>
```

In app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <ImageBrush x:Key="PageImageBackground" Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/bgimage.jpg"/>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PageBackground" EndPoint="3,3" StartPoint="0,0" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDFDFDD" Offset=".5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE8E8E6" Offset=".5"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PageBackground" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PageImageBackground" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```